# can someone further explain this C# code

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, predicatebuilder

I am using the PredicateBuilder class from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
```

this extension method is chaining Predicates with the OR operator. on the page, the explanation says

*We start by invoking the second expression with the first expression’s parameters. An Invoke expression calls another lambda expression using the given expressions as arguments. We can create the conditional expression from the body of the first expression and the invoked version of the second. The final step is to wrap this in a new lambda expression.*

---

so if for example i have

```
Predicate<Book> p1 = b => b.Title.Contains("economy");
Predicate<Book> p2 = b=>b.PublicationYear>2001;
Predicate chain = p1.And(p2);
```

I didn't quite get the exlanation. can someone please explain how the code of the extension method above is working?
thanks

Comment: What part is unclear to you? Can you elaborate?

Comment: the part of how the second expression is invoked with the first's parameters on the first line and then how the lambda expression is constructed and returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite the method body like this:

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.OrElse(
        expr1.Body,
        Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())
    ),
    expr1.Parameters);
```

We should also keep in mind that `expr1` is your existing expression that takes a `T` and returns a `bool`. Additionally, while the expression trees we are working with do not actually *do* anything (they *represent* something instead), I am going to use "do" henceforth because it makes for much easier reading. Technically for an expression tree to actually do something you have to [compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) it first and then invoke the resulting delegate.

Ok, so what do we have here? This is a lambda expression that takes whatever parameters `expr1` takes (see last line) and whose body, as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353063.aspx), is

> a `BinaryExpression` that represents a conditional OR operation that
>   evaluates the second operand only if the first operand evaluates to
>   false.

The first operand is `expr1.Body`, which means the resulting function (not actually a function, see note above) evaluates `expr1`. If the result is `true` it returns `true` on the spot. Otherwise, it invokes `expr2` with the same parameters as those passed to `expr1` (this means the single `T` parameter) and returns the result of that.

Comment: ok so if expre1 returns false, expr2 is invoked with the **same** parameter. that's what i missed.